# Can I be sued for acting as the US sales agent for a EU manufactured product that subsequently is accused of breaching a US patent?

Tags: united-states

If I sell a product in the US as a US resident sales agent on behalf of an EU seller of a product they manufacture in the EU that subsequently breaches a US patent can I be sued?

Answer (score 5):

[35 USC 271(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/271) says

> whoever without authority makes, uses, offers to sell, or sells any
> patented invention, within the United States or imports into the
> United States any patented invention during the term of the patent
> therefor, infringes the patent

Also, (c)

> Whoever offers to sell or sells within the United States or imports
> into the United States a component of a patented machine, manufacture,
> combination or composition, or a material or apparatus for use in
> practicing a patented process, constituting a material part of the
> invention, knowing the same to be especially made or especially
> adapted for use in an infringement of such patent, and not a staple
> article or commodity of commerce suitable for substantial
> noninfringing use, shall be liable as a contributory infringer.

Both an offer to sell and an actual sale are infringing activities.

Comment: That second one states as a condition, _"**knowing the same to be especially made or especially adapted for use in an infringement of such patent**, [AND ALSO MEETING other requisite condition]"_. If that isn't the case, the 2nd one would not apply.